# How to set VS Code code block background coloring from the Blockman extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using [the `leodevbro.blockman` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leodevbro.blockman). How can I set a new color to code block that I have marked in the picture?

Which property I should set in "workbench.colorCustomizations"?

Can I achieve it without adding a new extension?

[image: theme]

The color that I marked in picture should change with my settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the background of the editor panels, the colour customization point you're looking for is `editor.background`. Ex.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.background": "#ff0000", // TODO
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ff0000", // TODO

    // To find out what else is available, uncomment the following line,
    // and put your cursor at the end of it and trigger suggestions.
    // "editor.background
}
```

For blockman, see its docs: https://github.com/leodevbro/vscode-blockman#all-blockman-settings, which has the following in its readme:

> ```json
> "blockman.n04ColorComboPreset": "Classic Dark 1 (Gradients)", // This does not change VS Code theme. Choose preset combo of colors. Corresponding colors are overridden by custom colors (if not empty string). Also This setting can be overriden by the next 3 combo settings
> "blockman.n04Sub01ColorComboPresetForDarkTheme": "none", // Color combo to apply when current theme kind is Dark.
> "blockman.n04Sub02ColorComboPresetForLightTheme": "none", // Color combo to apply when current theme kind is Light.
> "blockman.n04Sub03ColorComboPresetForHighContrastTheme": "none", // Color combo to apply when current theme kind is High Contrast.
>
> "blockman.n05CustomColorOfDepth0": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
>
> "blockman.n06CustomColorOfDepth1": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n07CustomColorOfDepth2": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n08CustomColorOfDepth3": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n09CustomColorOfDepth4": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n10CustomColorOfDepth5": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
>
> "blockman.n11CustomColorOfDepth6": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n12CustomColorOfDepth7": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n13CustomColorOfDepth8": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n14CustomColorOfDepth9": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
> "blockman.n15CustomColorOfDepth10": "", // Any CSS color, e.g. rgb, rgba, hsl. Type 'none' for same color as editor background.
>
> "blockman.n17CustomColorOfFocusedBlock": "", // Requires 'Enable Focus' to be true/enabled. Type 'same' if you want it to be same color as if not focused.
> "blockman.n18CustomColorOfFocusedBlockBorder": "", // Requires 'Enable Focus' to be true/enabled. Type 'same' if you want it to be same color as if not focused.
> "blockman.n19CustomColorOfBlockBorder": "",
> "blockman.n20CustomColorOfDepth0Border": "",
>
> // Advanced Coloring:
> // Video instruction: https://youtu.be/UsET6-kPu90
>
> // Textual instruction:
> // '!' means disabled.
> // Advanced coloring string, if enabled, will override basic coloring settings.
>
> // Right side: sequence of colors/gradients.
>
> // Left side:
> // --- FIRST number relates priority,
> // --- SECOND number relates zero-based index of first item of first loop, So it splits the sequence into what should not be looped and what should be looped,
> // --- THIRD number relates loop part reversion (0: original, 1: reversed),
> // --- FOURTH number relates looping strategy (0: all the continuation items to be 'neutral', 'neutral' means it will be overriden by any other setting, 1: Only the last item will be looped. Yes, it will ignore the SECOND option number (split index), 2: loop as forward, 3: loop as pair of forward and backward).
>
> // 'neutral' color means it will be overriden by any other coloring setting.
> // 'basic' color means it will set a color from basic color settings.
>
> // 'transparent' and partially transparent colors work fine for borders, but backgrounds have some problems with such values,
> // so, if you type 'transparent' on background, it will be the color of VS Code editor backgound.
>
> "blockman.n33A01B1FromDepth0ToInwardForAllBorders": "!10,0,0,0; red > green > blue",
> "blockman.n33A01B2FromDepth0ToInwardForAllBackgrounds": "!10,1,0,3; hsl(235, 30%, 7%) > hsl(0, 0%, 7.1%) > hsl(0, 0%, 9.5%) > hsl(0, 0%, 11.15%) > hsl(0, 0%, 12.8%)",
>
> "blockman.n33A02B1FromFocusToOutwardForAllBorders": "!20,0,0,0; red > green > blue",
> "blockman.n33A02B2FromFocusToOutwardForAllBackgrounds": "!20,0,0,0; red > green > blue",
>
> "blockman.n33A03B1FromDepth0ToInwardForFocusTreeBorders": "!30,1,0,2; linear-gradient(to right, hsl(251, 22%, 25%), hsl(292, 20%, 18%)) > linear-gradient(to right, hsl(20, 50%, 30%), hsl(250, 30%, 30%))",
> "blockman.n33A03B2FromDepth0ToInwardForFocusTreeBackgrounds": "!30,0,0,0; red > green > blue",
>
> "blockman.n33A04B1FromFocusToOutwardForFocusTreeBorders": "40,0,0,0; basic",
> "blockman.n33A04B2FromFocusToOutwardForFocusTreeBackgrounds": "40,0,0,0; basic",
>
> "blockman.n33A05B1FromFocusToInwardForAllBorders": "!50,0,0,0; red > green > blue",
> "blockman.n33A05B2FromFocusToInwardForAllBackgrounds": "!50,0,0,0; red > green > blue",
> ```

For code blocks rendered in things like Markdown Preview and extension pages, use `textCodeBlock.background`.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the background color use "workbench.colorCustomization", inside that you can give "editor.background" color value what you want. This is the example from my code:

```js
workbench.colorCustomizations": {
     "tab.activeBackground": "#23272e",
     "tab.inactiveBackground": "#2c2f38",
     "tab.hoverBackground": "#323842",
     "activityBar.background": "#2c2f38",
     "activityBar.foreground": "#d7dae0",
     "activityBarBadge.background": "#d7dae0",
     "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#23272e",
     "badge.background": "#404754",
     "sideBar.background": "#282c34",
     "sideBar.foreground": "#abb2bf",
     "tab.activeBorder": "#d19a66",
     "editor.background": "#23272e",
     "editor.foreground": "#abb2bf",
     "button.background": "#404754",
     "debugToolBar.background": "#21252b",
     "descriptionForeground": "#abb2bf",
     "dropdown.background": "#1e2227",
     "dropdown.border": "#404754",
     "statusBar.background": "#404754",
     "titleBar.activeBackground": "#404754",
     "focusBorder": "#404754",
     "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#2c313a",
     "panel.border": "#404754",
     "scrollbarSlider.background": "#4e566660",
     "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#747d9180",
     "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#5a637580"
   },
```